# convert tidyverse rowwise operation to data.table solution

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

I have a dataframe with millions of rows and tens of columns that I need to apply a rowwise  operation.  My solution below  works using `dplyr` but I hope  a switch to data.table will speed things up. Any help converting  the below code to a `data.table` version would be appreciated.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(trend)
 
df = structure(list(id = 1:2, var = c(3L, 9L), col1_x = c("[(1,2,3)]", 
                                                              "[(100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20)]"), col2_x = c("[(2,4,6)]", "[(100,50,25,12,6,3,1,1,1)]"
                                                              )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df  = df %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("x"),~ gsub("[][()]", "", .)))

x_cols = df  %>% 
  select(ends_with("x")) %>% 
  names()

df  = df %>% 
  rowwise()  %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(x_cols) ,~  ifelse(var<=4,0,sens.slope(as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(., ','))))$estimates[[1]]),.)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Some comments rather than a full answer.  Converting to data.table is not a magic bullet that will make inefficient code efficient.  1) If you control the upstream data, export it into an appropriate format and read it into R properly instead of parsing text strings to numeric. 2) If not, parse the strings to numeric *before* the rowwise computations. 3).  `var` is a row constant, split out `var <= 4` instead of checking it repeatedly per row . 4) You want a single coefficient so calculate just that - Sen's slope is trivial to compute, you don't need to calculate the full model.

Comment: For this particular example, I don't see the reason to use rowwise. For Row-wise operations you can still use some much faster [Column-wise way](https://thatdatatho.com/row-wise-operations-column-wise-way-tidyr-pivot_longer/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=row-wise-operations-column-wise-way-tidyr-pivot_longer). The one that uses transpose() is the one I prefer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While what @Ritchie Sacramento wrote is absolutely true, here's the information you asked for.

First, I want to start with `set` or `:=`. When you see the keyword `set` (which can just be *part* of the function name) or the `:=` symbol, you've told `data.table` not to make copies of the data. Without declaring or declaration (that pesky `=` or `<-`), you've changed the data table. This is one of the key methods to prevent wasted memory with this package.

> Keep in mind that the environment pane in RStudio is triggered to update when it registers that operator (`=` or `<-`), creating something new. Since you did a replace-in-place, the environment pane may reflect incorrect information. You can use the `refresh` icon (top right of the pane), or you can print the object to the console to check.
>
> As soon as you declare anything that the pane identifies, everything in the pane is updated.

Change a data frame to a `data.table`. (Notice that keyword—`set`!) Both of these do the same thing. However, one copies everything in memory and makes it again. (Naming the frame the same thing does not prevent copies.)

```
setDT(df)

df <- data.table(df)
```

I'm not going to start with your first code blurb. I'm starting with the name extraction.

You wrote:

```
x_cols = df  %>% 
  select(ends_with("x")) %>% 
  names()
# [1] "col1_x" "col2_x"
```

There are many ways to get this information. This is what I did. Note that this doesn't really have anything to do with `data.table`. I just used base R here. You could use a data frame the same way.

```
xcols <- names(df)[endsWith(names(df), 'x')]
# [1] "col1_x" "col2_x"
```

I'm going to use this object, `xcols` in the remaining examples. (Why keep reiterating the same declaration?)

You wrote the following to remove the brackets and parentheses.

```
df = df %>%
  mutate(across(ends_with("x"),~ gsub("[][()]", "", .)))
#   id var                      col1_x                 col2_x
# 1  1   3                       1,2,3                  2,4,6
# 2  2   9 100,90,80,70,60,50,40,30,20 100,50,25,12,6,3,1,1,1
```

There are several ways you could do this, whether in a data frame or a `data.table`. Here are a couple of methods you can use with `data.table`. These do the exact same thing as each other and your code.

Note the `:=`, which means the table changed.
In the first example, I used `.SD` and `.SDcols`. These are data column selection tools. You use `.SD` in place of the column name when you want to use more than one column. Then use `.SDcols` to tell `data.table` what columns you're trying to use.  By annotating `(xcols)`, where `xcols` is my variable representing my column names to use, this tells `data.table` to replace the data in the columns used for the aggregation.

The difference between these two is how I used `lapply`, which doesn't have anything to do with `data.table`. If you need more info on this function, you can ask me, or you can look through the many Q & As out there already.

```
df[, 
   (xcols) := lapply(.SD, function(k) gsub("[][()]", "", k)),
   .SDcols = xcols]

df[,
   (xcols) := lapply(.SD, gsub, pattern = "[][()]", 
                     replacement = ""),
   .SDcols = xcols]
```

Your last request was based on this code.

```
df %>% 
  rowwise()  %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(x_cols),
                ~ifelse(var <= 5, 0, sens.slope(
                  as.numeric(unlist(
                    strsplit(., ','))))$estimates[[1]]),.)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Since you used `var` to delineate when to apply this, I've used the `by` argument (as in `dplyr`'s `group_by`). In terms of the other requirements, you'll see `.SD` and `lapply` again.

```
df[,
   (xcols) := lapply(.SD, 
          function(k) {
            ifelse(var <= 3, 0, 
                   sens.slope(as.numeric(strsplit(k, ",")[[1]])
                   )$estimates[[1]])
          }), by = var, .SDcols = xcols]
```

If you think about how these differ, you may find that, in a lot of ways, they aren't all that different. For example, in this last *translation*, you may see a similar approach in `dplyr` that I used.

```
df %>% group_by(var) %>% 
  mutate(across(all_of(x_cols),
                ~ifelse(var <= 5, 0, sens.slope(
                  as.numeric(unlist(
                    strsplit(., ','))))$estimates[[1]])))
```

Comment: (1) In the `data.table` version, you might improve performance by changing `ifelse(var <= 3, ..)]` to `if (first(var) <= 3) 0 else ...`. It won't be meaningful here, but it might help a little with the 10mi rows. (2) For the OP, the need for `strsplit` is easily an expensive thing to do, you might consider storing your `x_cols` columns as list-columns instead of strings. Doing this once is just as expensive as embedding it here, but if you do anything else on those columns that looks at the _numbers_ themselves, you'll pay dividends.